# compression option in fastparquet is not consistent

Tags: python, pandas, compression, fastparquet

According to the [project page of fastparquet](https://pypi.org/project/fastparquet/), `fastparquet` support various compression methods

> Optional (compression algorithms; gzip is always available):
>
> ```
> snappy (aka python-snappy)
> lzo
> brotli
> lz4
> zstandard
> ```

especially [`zstandard`](https://facebook.github.io/zstd/) is modern algorithm that provides high compression ratios as well as impressive fast compression/decompression speed. And this is what I want in fastparquet.

But in the doc of [fastparquet.write](https://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fastparquet.write)

> compression to apply to each column, e.g. GZIP or SNAPPY or a dict
>   like {"col1": "SNAPPY", "col2": None} to specify per column
>   compression types. In both cases, the compressor settings would be the
>   underlying compressor defaults. To pass arguments to the underlying
>   compressor, each dict entry should itself be a dictionary:
>
> ```
> {
>     col1: {
>         "type": "LZ4",
>         "args": {
>             "compression_level": 6,
>             "content_checksum": True
>          }
>     },
>     col2: {
>         "type": "SNAPPY",
>         "args": None
>     }
>     "_default": {
>         "type": "GZIP",
>         "args": None
>     }
> }
> ```

Nothing mentioned about zstandard. What is worse, if I write

```
fastparquet.write('outfile.parq', df, compression='LZ4')
```

It pops up errors saying

> Compression 'LZ4' not available.  Options: ['GZIP', 'UNCOMPRESSED']

So `fastparquest` only support 'GZIP'? This is quite a discrepancy from the project page! Do I missing some packages? How to use fastparquest with all project page stated compression algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may be missing some packages. Your system must have have the python LZ4 and/or zstandard bindings first. See [the source code](https://github.com/dask/fastparquet/blob/master/fastparquet/compression.py#L65) for more details.

- For LZ4: if `import lz4.block` gives a `ModuleNotFoundError`, then go ahead and install with `pip install lz4`.
- Similarly for zstandard: `pip install zstandard`
- And for brotli: `pip install brotlipy`
- And lzo: `pip install python-lzo`
- And snappy: `pip install python-snappy`

Comment: Thank you so much！After install all packages as you suggested. Now `fastparquet` has options `['BROTLI', 'GZIP', 'LZ4', 'LZO', 'SNAPPY', 'UNCOMPRESSED', 'ZSTD']`

Comment: I found a problem in source code. It seems that compression level is only controllable in GZIP mode.